# Scala: iteration 2d array to do operation

Tags: arrays, scala, operation

A newbie here.

```
val arr_one = Array(Array(1, 2), Array(3, 4), Array(5, 6),Array(x, y)..and so on)
val arr_two = Array(Array(2,3), Array(4, 5), Array(6, 7))
var tempArr = ArrayBuffer[Double]()
```

I want to multiply arr_one and arr_two. for example

Iteration1 :`Array(1*2+2*3, 1*4 +2*5, 1*6+2*7 )` assign to tempArr

Iteration2 :`Array(3*2+4*3, 3*4 +4*5, 3*6+4*7)` assign to tempArr

Iteration3 :`Array(5*2+6*3, 5*4 +6*5, 5*6+6*7)` assign to tempArr

I knew that if

```
val x = Array(1, 2) ; val y = Array(Array(2,3), Array(4, 5), Array(6, 7))
```

I can use `y map {x zip _ map{case(a, b) => a * b} sum}`

But If x like arr_one form, I don't know how to use `for loop or something else` to do that.

I really have on idea.

How can I do this in scala?

Really thanks.

Comment: What happens to your tempArr between iterations? do you use it inside the iteration, or do you somehow combine it with the previous value of tempArr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this is what you need:

```
val tmp = arr_one map ((arr1) => {arr_two map (arr2 => (arr1 zip arr2) map {case(a, b) => a * b} reduce (_ + _))} )
```

And to get `ArrayBuffer` simply use :

```
tmpArr = tmp.toBuffer
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this does what you need, without any mutable state and "iterations" - it uses the "[for-comprehension](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html)" syntax which is kind of a non-imperative for-loop - in other words, instead of *changing state* in each iteration, it *returns a value* which is the sequence of results per "iteration":

```
val result: Array[Array[Int]] = for (arr1 <- arr_one) yield {
  for (arr2 <- arr_two) yield multArrays(arr1, arr2)
}
```

Assuming that `multArrays` has the following signature:

```
def multArrays(arr1: Array[Int], arr2: Array[Int]): Int
```

That calculates the value for each cell. A naive implementation (assuming arrays have size 2) would be:

```
def multArrays(arr1: Array[Int], arr2: Array[Int]): Int = {
  arr1(0) * arr2(0) + arr1(1) * arr2(1)
}
```

But of course this can be generalized to any size arrays.

Comment: oh, just realized you are interested in a result of the form `Array[Double]` - but not clear what logic should be applied to get it. Hope the answer helps anyway, perhaps you can figure out the rest... If what you need is standard matrix multiplication, there's a nice (although not trivial) implementation here: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Scala

Comment: I got it. Thanks you for helping me.